# Swift adding view programmatically covers UI controls in interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, interface-builder

I'm working on an ios app in which I want to show a google map view and a text label containing the location information in the same super view. My expected scenario is the map view fills the whole screen and the text label hover above it. When I do this, I create the map view in code but drag the label from object library in interface builder. However, it seems controls in IB will be initialized before ViewDidLoad is called. So `view.addSubview(mapView)` will add the map view but cover all the controls in IB. Is there any way to solve this problem if I still want to use IB building my UI? Thanks!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Set up Maps
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self

        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()


        let defaultLocation = CLLocation(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                                              longitude: defaultLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                                              zoom: zoomLevel)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        // Add the map to the view, hide it until we've got a location update.
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.isHidden = true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't u take mapview on IB only?

Comment: I'm a beginner and just follow google's tutorial where it demos in this way...

Comment: So, the first thing to do is understand view hierarchy. Follow that up with either bringing your `mapView` to the front or send things to the back. Finally, understand the *full* view lifecycle and consider `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to bring this view to the front. What's the issue? Since you didn't inlace *code* I down voted and believe if you would show us how you *programmatically* add this view there is a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: sorry about that. I edited it.